# CSS Vertical Alignment of Div

Tags: css, html, image

I have a heading, then below that I display a selection of items next to each other. On the same line as the selection of items I display a single picture.

The issue I'm having is that I want the single image (X) to be aligned so that the bottom of it is in line with the bottom of the selection of items (A, B & C). Eg.

```
H1 Title             ----------
                     |        |
                     |        |
                     |    X   |
-----  -----  -----  |        |
| A |  | B |  | C |  |        |
-----  -----  -----  ----------
```

The issue I'm having is that it appears like so:

```
H1 Title

-----  -----  -----  ----------
| A |  | B |  | C |  |        |
-----  -----  -----  |        |
                     |    X   |
                     |        |
                     |        |
                     ----------
```

Here is the HTML Im using:

```
<h1>H1 Title</h1>

<div id="items">
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="single_image">
        <img src="myImage.png" />
</div>
```

The CSS I'm using is:

```
#items { 
    float:left; 
}

#items ul { 
    list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; 
}

#items ul li { 
    display:inline; float:left; 
    margin-bottom:20px; font-size:22px; 
}

#single_image { }

#single_image img { 
    float:right; height:130px; 
    width:inherit; margin-right:40px; 
}
```

Please could someone help me out? I can't work out the issue. I tried using the vertical align attribute on the img in the CSS, however it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: add a jsfiddle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is a fixed size, a quick fix for this problem would simply be to use a negative margin-top, so that the image is its own height above - so bottom is actually where the top is now.

E.g. If the image is 130px height, do:

```
#single_image img { margin-top: -130px; }
```

Comment: I've removed the footer here. If you wish to indicate what your Twitter account is, please put it in your profile. There are scripts that crawl SO profiles and associate Twitter accounts with them that way, so it's a more effective means of people finding you than in answers.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to wrap them in a container and absolutely position #items to the bottom of the container. Here is a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/5csWH/

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>H1 Title</h1>
    <div id="items">
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="single_image">
        <img src="myImage.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#items          { float:left; }
#items ul       { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
#items ul li    { float:left; margin-right:20px; font-size:22px; width: 50px; background: #DDD; }

#single_image       { }
#single_image img   { float:right; height:130px; width:inherit; background: #DDD; }

.container { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; background: #EEE; position: relative; }
.clearfix { clear: both; }​
```